# Special values of Dirichlet L-functions at negative integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $k$ be an even positive integer. Denote $L(1-k,\chi_D)$ the Special value at $1-k$ of the Dirichlet $L$-function associated to a real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$.
Changing the fundamental discriminant $D$, and fixing a prime number $p$, can we expect any type of congruence relation modulo $p$ between the values $L(1-k,\chi_D)$ ?
( There is works in this direction of K.Ribet and P.Deligne but It's not what I am looking for ) any references please can help me !
In particular suppose that $p-1|k$, can we find $D>0$ such that $p$ is not divinding $L(1-k,\chi_D)$ ?

Comment: For the second question it turns to look when $L_{p}(1-k,\chi_D)$ is a $p$-adic unit. It seems to be studied by L.Washington !