# Divisor function and special values of Dirichlet L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $k$ an even positive integer and $p$ an odd prime number such that $p-1|k$. Let $D>0$ be ranging over fundamental discriminants of real quadratic fields. Consider the following modular form $$G_{k,D}=\frac{1}{2}L(1-k,(\frac{D}{.}))+\sum_{n\geq1}(\sum_{d|n}(\frac{D}{d})d^{k-1})q^n.$$ 
 - Is there any result about $\mod{p}$ congruences for the function $\sigma_{k-1,D}(n)=\sum_{d|n}(\frac{D}{d})d^{k-1}$ ?
 - How can we use the above modular form to deduce $\mod{p}$ congruence for $\frac{1}{2}L(1-k,(\frac{D}{.}))$ ?

Comment: This seems to be a virtually exact duplicate of of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263248/special-values-of-dirichlet-l-functions-at-negative-integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special values of Dirichlet L-functions at negative integers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263248/special-values-of-dirichlet-l-functions-at-negative-integers)